# Meaning of "non se ne parla"

Tags: verbs, meaning, pronouns, word-order

I recently saw this phrase on Facebook, and I got very confused, because shouldn't it be:

> Si non ne parla

?

I know that (or at least I was told; correct me if I am wrong) in Italian, you say:

> Si non lo sa mai

("One never knows that/it")
For example, this could be referring to:

> Si non sa mai quando arrivano gli autobus in Italia-->Si non lo sa mai

I was told that you would not say:

> Non se lo sa mai

So why can't the same be said for

> Non se ne parla

?

Is it because the "si" is used as a reflexive here and not as the English "one" or the German "man"? But if so, what would that phrase mean? Would it mean that the person doesn't talk to himself/herself about something? Moreover, I have tried to look up the verb "parlarsene" and have come up with nothing. Please help; thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: In spoken language, it simply means "no way" as in "no way I'm doing that", for instance. That is its most common use for this phrase, although litereally it means "we don't talk about it".

Comment: Actually, a literal translation would be more like, “One doesn’t talk about it.”

Answer (score 5):

“Si non ne parla” is ungrammatical. The negation must go before the reflexive pronoun, which is changed into *se* because followed by another pronoun (*ne*):

> non se ne parla

that is, *we/people don't talk about that*. It can be *non se ne parla nemmeno*: *not even talk about it*.

Similarly, it is *non si sa mai*, for the same reason.

Comment: But then if what you're saying is true, why isn't it "non ce ne parliamo"?

Comment: @user49558 Nobody would say “non ce ne parliamo”.

Comment: If that's the case, then the "si" in "non se ne parla" isn't a reflexive pronoun, but more like an English "one" isn't it?

Comment: @user49558 No, it is a reflexive pronoun, it's the *si impersonale*.

Comment: In any case, I remember someone Italian specifically telling me that "non se lo sa mai" is wrong because in this case the "si" isn't reflexive but more like the English "one", German "man" or French "on"

Comment: @user49558 It's quite difficult to sort out a rule; simply it is *non si sa mai*; the pronoun *lo* here has no place.

Comment: Wait, why is the "lo" discarded? In regular speech I often say (for example) "Lo so già". Is that wrong as well?

Comment: @user49558 You don't use the pronoun when the object is expressed: *non si sa mai quando passano gli autobus*.

Comment: Yes I know that, but what about in the case where you want to say "we/the people never know **that/it**"? Wouldn't that be "non se lo sa mai"?

Comment: Per esempio: "Oh, scusi, sa quando passa l'autobus 56?" "Eh, mi dispiace, ma qui non se lo sa mai; qualche volta arriva 20 minuti in ritardo."

Comment: @user49558 Here it can be “qui non si sa mai” or also *qui non lo si sa mai* (colloquial). The form *non se lo sa* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Si is not reflexive here! It may be impersonal or passivant, and I'm not quite decided, but it surely isn't reflexive: the object of the phrase can't talk about itself, nor can the speaker!

Answer (score 1):

> I recently saw this phrase on Facebook, and I got very confused, because shouldn't it be:
>
> > Si non ne parla
> >     ?

That sentence is ungrammatical, because Italian clitics always have to immediately precede, or be suffixed to, a verb or the word *ecco*:

> ***Lo voglio*** vedere. / *Voglio **vederlo**.* — I want to see it.
>
> ***Guardalo***! (informal) / ***Lo guardi***! (formal) — Look at it!
>
> ***Avendolo*** trovato, **se lo mise** in tasca. / Having found it, he put it in his pocket.
>
> ***Eccolo***!  — There it is!

---

> I know that (or at least I was told; correct me if I am wrong) in Italian, you say:
>
> > Si non lo sa mai

That sentence is incorrect for the same reason. I think what you *have* been told is that you say, “Non lo si sa mai.” (Though this is rare. You usually just say, “Non si sa mai.”)

Now the question becomes, why do you say, “Non **lo si** sa mai” (*si* is in the second position), but, “Non **se ne** parla” (*se* is in the first position)?

Simple, because Italian clitics follow a certain order:

1. *mi*
2. *gli*, *le* (dative)
3. *vi*
4. *ti*
5. *ci*
6. reflexive *si*
7. *lo*, *la*, *li*, *le* (accusative)
8. impersonal *si*
9. *ne*

[image: The order of the clitics]

(Patrizia Cordin & Andrea Calabrese, 1988, *I pronomi personali*, in *Grande grammatica italiana di consultazione. Vol 1*, p. 589)

As you can see, impersonal *si* goes *before ne*, but comes *after lo*.

Answer (score 0):

*Non se ne parla* is an idiomatic form that could be roughly translated as *It's out of discussion* as in *absolutely not*.

Answer (score -1):

As someone replied before me, "Non si sa mai" is a common idiomatic expression which is the equivalent of the English "You never know". Mainly used in colloquial language.

Notice that this sort of idiomatic expressions, of which there are a number in Italian language, usually don't follow a specific grammatical pattern, so they can be somehow an "exception" to the rules. 
I suggest you to learn them *by heart*, and focus instead on their usage in context rather than on the grammar.

In these specific expressions the *si* particle is not used as a reflexive pronoun, but as a non-personal pronoun ("*pronome impersonale*"), exactly as *mann* in German or *on* in French.

Said this, I'm going now to comment your questions:

**No. 1**

> [...] shouldn't it be: "Si non ne parla"?

No. Let's analyze the phrase logically, and let's suppose by absurd that:

- The subject would be "he/she" (it's implied, since "parla" is a III sing. person verb). (Hypothesys).

There would be a discrepance between the subject, the *ne* particle and the impersonal pronoun *si*, because if the subject is "he/she" it is then uncorrect to use a non-personal pronoun; this causes the phrase to sound *weird*, and to be semantically incorrect.

In other words, your mistake (which is perfectly understandable, as I said at the beginning) is simply logic: you did not negate the proposition properly.

> Se ne parla --> **Non** se ne parla

Where *se* is exactly the same of *si* impersonal.

**No. 2**

> I know that (or at least I was told; correct me if I am wrong) in
>   Italian, you say: *Si non lo sa mai*

It's again a matter of logical analysys of the phrase, as described in question No. 1;

> Lo si sa (sempre) ---> **Non** lo si sa (mai)

Please note that words order in Italian is, sometimes, particulary relevant, especially if you want to sound "natural".

**No. 3**

> I was told that you would not say: *Non se lo sa mai*, So why can't the same be said for *Non se ne parla*.

- Non (negative p.) se (subject, impersonal p.) ne ("of it") parla (predicate, III sing).
- Non (negation) lo (object) si (subject, impersonal) sa (predicate) mai (adverb).

Same pattern.
Note that the pattern Subject --> Predicate --> ... --> Adverb(s) is the standard sentences pattern in Italian.

I hope to have been helpful - and exaustive.
Sorry for my English, though!